# MOCKITO How to mock object method if object is not a bean

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, testing, mockito

Inside the method I'm testing, I have this:

```
val client = PushClient() 
... 
client.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk)
```

PushClient is not a bean as you can see... how can I mock the sendPushNotificationsAsync method?

tried like this, but doesn't work, doesn't get called...

```
        val mockPushClient = mock(PushClient::class.java)
        val ticket = ExpoPushTicket()
        ticket.status = Status.OK
        val cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(listOf(ticket))
        Mockito.doReturn(cf).`when`(mockPushClient).sendPushNotificationsAsync(any())
```

Comment: It is not clear form your question if  `client` is an instance or method scope variable and that matters.

Comment: I have been in your situation before. If you are using Spring, the right thing to do is to define a bean and inject it as a dependency to your class. This way you can test it. This would be your best option if it is possible for your project.

Comment: I was going to say much the same as @StefanZhelyazkov which is that the test subject should not create the PushClient instance itself but rather only depend on that object. This will make mocking it out easier with Mockito. In a circumstance like this, I have also found JMockit to be useful to overcome cases where you cannot change the test subject but haven't used it much with Kotlin--think it works, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(Object targetObject, String name, @Nullable Object value)
```

method to mock the objects which are not beans.

Comment: Using Kotlin: I had to make 'val client = ...' to the class field, then in test adding `val client = mock<PushClient>()
given(client.send(any())).willReturn(data)
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(testedClass, "client", client)`. Taken from https://www.baeldung.com/java-mockito-private-fields#enable-mocking-with-spring-test

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question if client is an instance or method scoped variable and that matters.

In the latter case you could do somthing like:

```
public class ClassUnderTest{
    
    public void methodUnderTest(){
        val client = getClient(); //now we can override
    }
    
    protected PushClient getClient(){
        return new PushClient();
    }
}

pubic class TestClass{

    private ClassUnderTest testClass = new TestableClassUnderTest();
    
    public void testMethodUnderTest(){
        //dostuff
    }

    //extends the class being tested so we can return a mock client
    protected class TestableClassUnderTest extends ClassUnderTest{
        @Override
        public PushClient getClient(){
            PushClient client = Mockito.mock(PushClient.class);
            //configure mock 

            return client;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Otherwise, use PowerMock to set private instance variables.

Comment: so here is simplified version

I have a Service that has a sendNotification method

```
sendNotification(notification){
    val client = PushClient() /* PushClient is class from external lib */
    val response = client.sendPushNotificationsAsync(notification)
}

Comment: Do it like I have suggested then.

Comment: and I want to mock sendPushNotificationsAsync method, so it doesnt send the notification on external server/api